# How can I load WPFToolkit assembly in Powershell

Tags: powershell, assemblies, load, wpftoolkit

I have installed WPF Toolkit:

```
Location: C:\Program Files\WPF Toolkit\v3.5.40320.1\WPFToolkit.dll 
Name: WPFToolkit, Version=3.5.40128.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 
Type: Library
```

I can load it by full path:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Program Files\WPF Toolkit\v3.5.40320.1\WPFToolkit.dll")
```

But can't load by assembly name:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("WPFToolkit, Version=3.5.40128.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35")

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("WPFToolkit, Version=3.5.40128.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35")
```

What is a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loading by assembly name doesn't work because the WPFToolkit assembly is neither in GAC nor in the PowerShell directory. There are several options:

- load it by path
- add it to the GAC
- change powershell.exe.config to look 
  in the WPF Toolkit directory
- handle the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve
  event (not particulary easy in
  PowerShell V1)

Comment: I thought it was in the GAC (confused by VS "Add Reference" dialog).

Comment: yeah, the VS "Add Reference" dialog actually displays a registry-backed list of assemblies

Comment: "handle the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event (not particulary easy in PowerShell V1)"
What about in Powershell V2?